# Spring Cloud Distributed tracing - Span does not work

Tags: spring, cloud, trace, boot, micrometer

I have a problem with my distributed tracing using Spring Cloud with Spring Boot3. Under Spring Cloud on the website, only Sleuth is listed, but this can't be used anymore. Hence, I'm using Micrometer Observation. It works out of the box with Zipkin.

The Problem starts when making requests from one service, the request is on a different thread. It will list each step as one Span in Zipkin instead of bundeling them. I guess that is expected due to the threads, I wanted to deal with it like so:

```
  Observation availabilityServiceObservation = Observation.createNotStarted("availabilityLookup",
                this.observationRegistry);
        return availabilityServiceObservation.observe(() -> {
            AvailabilityResponse[] responses = clientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://availability-service/api/availability", i -> i.queryParam("names", items).build())
                    .retrieve().bodyToMono(AvailabilityResponse[].class).block();

            assert responses != null;
            Boolean result = Arrays.stream(responses).allMatch(AvailabilityResponse::isAvailable);
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(result)) {
                bookingRepository.save(booking);
                return "Booking completed";
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not available");
            }
        });
```

But that does not work, it still shows everything as one Span. What is needed to combine everything under one root in Zipkin?